# How to write a php unit test to check instance of datetime object in php?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following codes trying to write a unit test for the following codes but havent been able to do so. Can anyone help me write a phpunit test for the following lines of codes.

```
if (!($start instanceof DateTime)) {
throw new BadRequestHttpException('Invalid start date');
}
if (!($end instanceof DateTime)) {
throw new BadRequestHttpException('Invalid end date');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for e.g you have function with name `validateStartEndDate` in `MyRepository`,

```
    public function yourFunction($start, $end)
    {
        if (!($start instanceof DateTime)) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Invalid start date');
        }
        if (!($end instanceof DateTime)) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Invalid end date');
        }
    }
```

Now its unit tests will be look like:

```
class YouTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
    * @test
    * @expectedException BadRequestHttpException
    * @expectedExceptionMessage Invalid start date
    */
    public function test_nor_allow_invalid_start_date()
    {
        $start = new Date();
        $yourRepo->yourFunction($start, new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
    * @test
    * @expectedException BadRequestHttpException
    * @expectedExceptionMessage Invalid end date
    */
    public function test_nor_allow_invalid_end_date()
    {
        $end = new Date();
        $yourRepo->yourFunction(new \DateTime(), $end);
    }
}
```